# Коллекции и списки в java. Использование типизированного и нетипизированного итератора

Tags: java, коллекции, итераторы

Дано 3 класса:

1. База данных о кино - содержит список фильмов и актеров.
2. Фильм - список актеров, которые в нем играют.
3. Актер - список фильмов в которых играл.

Необходимо:

1. Найти актера, который не играл ни в одном фильме, используя типизированный итератор.
2. Составить список актеров, с которыми в одном фильме играл данный актер. - тизированный цикл for-each.
3. Найти фильм с наибольшим количеством актеров. - нетипизированный итератор.

Проблема заключается в том, что не получается добавить один итератор в другой так как они имеют разный тип (1 относится к актерам, а 2 - к фильмам). 
Классы:

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Film film1 = new Film("Harry Potter");
        Film film2 = new Film("Split");
        Film film3 = new Film("Victor Frankenstein");

        Actor actor1 = new Actor("Daniel Redcliff");
        Actor actor2 = new Actor("Emma Watson");
        Actor actor3 = new Actor("James McAvoy");
        Actor actor4 = new Actor("BattleField Overwatch");

        Database.addFilm(film1);
        Database.addFilm(film2);
        Database.addFilm(film3);
        Database.addActor(actor1);
        Database.addActor(actor2);
        Database.addActor(actor3);
        Database.addActor(actor4);

        film1.addActor(actor1);
        film1.addActor(actor2);
        film2.addActor(actor3);
        film3.addActor(actor1);
        film3.addActor(actor3);
        actor1.addFilm(film1);
        actor1.addFilm(film3);
        actor2.addFilm(film1);
        actor3.addFilm(film2);
        actor3.addFilm(film3);
    }
}
public class Database {
    private static List<Film> allfilms = new ArrayList();
    public static void addFilm(Film film) {
        allfilms.add(film);
    }

    private static List<Actor> allactors = new ArrayList();
    public static void addActor(Actor actor) {
        allactors.add(actor);
    }

    public static List<Actor> getActors(){
        return allactors;
    }
    public static List<Film> getFilms(){
        return allfilms;
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class Film{
    private String name;
    private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList();
    public Film(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addActor(Actor actor) {
        this.actors.add(actor);
    }
    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return this.actors;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Actor{
    private String name;
    private List<Film> films = new ArrayList();
    public Actor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addFilm(Film film) {
        this.films.add(film);
    }
    public List<Film> getFilms(){
        return this.films;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще у вас ужасно сложная структура хранения данных. Нарисуйте UML и вы ужаснетесь. Так не делают. У вас ссылки из всех классов во все. Это очень излишне. И подерживать целостность такой структуры со временем будет сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот написал метод для первого вопроса. Какие сложности?

```
private static List<Actor> notFilmed() {
        List<Actor> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator<Actor> actorIterator = Database.getActors().iterator();
        while (actorIterator.hasNext()) {
            Actor actor = actorIterator.next();
            Iterator<Film> filmIterator = Database.getFilms().iterator();

            boolean present = false;
            while (filmIterator.hasNext()) {
                Film film = filmIterator.next();
                if (film.getActors().contains(actor)) {
                    present = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!present) {
                resultList.add(actor);
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

Выдает список из одного актера - Actor{name='BattleField Overwatch'}